# ПЛИС: Генерация диаграммы с помощью TCL

Tags: tcl

Как при помощи TCL консольки сгенерировать ранее несуществующий файл vwf(vector waveform file) для quartus II

Comment: Боюсь, вы не по адресу. За последние несколько месяцев вопросов по плисам тут не было, насколько я помню :-(

Comment: Странно. Разобрался сам. В итоге написал кучу скриптов под квартус